# Invalid Type Promotion error in numpy expression

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to generate a date from a column--"BR Status Date"--in my pandas dataframe into a new column I've created--"Cand Not Interest Date"--but only if another column--"Current HR Status"--contains certain text.  Like so:

```
BR['Cand Not Interest Date'] = np.where(BR['Current HR status'].str.contains('Candidate Not Interested'),
                                                          BR['BR Status Date'],0)
```

But, I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I replaced the 0 with np.datetime64('NaT').

Like so:

```
BR['Cand Not Interest Date'] = np.where(BR['Current HR status'].str.contains('Candidate Not Interested'),BR['BR Status Date'],np.datetime64('NaT'))
```